# How do I replace or reconfigure my Team Build server if I switch to Mercurial

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, mercurial

I'm considering moving from TFS source control to Mercurial with HgScc.  How do I replace the Team Build server aspect of my Team Foundation system or reconfigure Team Build to use Mercurial to pull the newest branch?  Currently all of our released to production binaries are build on our build server to prevent workstation specific changes, libraries, settings, etc from creating incompatible builds, keeping release builds from tying up workstations, and generally for quality control.  How do I do this if I switch our C# .NET development to a Mercurial based version control system?

Comment: I might be wrong, but it doesn't look like Team Build can use anything other than the source control part of TFS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181710(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can continue to build with TeamBuild without some pretty ugly hacks. I would recommend looking at either:

- [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) from JetBrains.  I love this product.  It's free for smaller usage, with commercial options.
- [CruiseControl .net](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) - Used this before moving to TeamCity, worked fairly well but it's been a few years for me.

  I applaud your desire to do builds off of your dev machines - really the best way to go in my opinion.

Comment: You're right, Team Build can use another source control system by modifying the build process workflow (some ugly hacks). However, another consideration is that Team Build requires a TFS server to initiate a build, regardless of the source control used.

Comment: Ended up using TeamCity and it is fantastic.  Thanks.